# Class "X" not found in CakePHP 2.1 since php 5.4

Tags: php, cakephp

I have updated my machine from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.4 and my CakePHP (version 2.1.1) app keeps getting these errors:

> Fatal Error: Class 'String' not found in .../Behavior.php on line ...
>
> Fatal Error: Class 'Debugger' not found in .../Component.php on line ...

Etc.

The errors are really not useful, since the LINE and FILE of the error always state the end bracket of the class declaration.

After a lot of searching, I managed to solve SOME of the errors by adding proper public/private function declarations and strong parameter typing, A.K.A.:

```
function beforeSave($Model) {}

//becomes
public function beforeSave(Model $Model){}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After transferring to PHP5.4, you have to cleanup a lot of "bad practices" in your code.

**Strong-typed parameter definition in extended methods**

This means that you have to write the class of the objects which the method receives just before the variable name. This is only needed for methods which replace parent's class methods, not for all methods. If unsure, just check the method declaration in the parent class in the core files or API.

```
// Behavior code
public function afterSave(Model $model, $created) //GOOD 
function aferSave($model) //NOT GOOD
// Component code
public function shutdown(Controller $Controller) // GOOD
function shutdown($Controller) // BAD
```

**Remove "Call-time pass by reference"**

I've seen a lot of people passing arround Controller and Model objects in functions BY REFERENCE:

```
function beforeSave(&$Model)
```

This throws an error and is wrong.
Just remove the ampersand before the variable. You will not break any functionality, because Objects are already passed by reference in PHP, and as I get it, [this was removed in PHP 5.4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php).

**Declare all method parameters in extending methods**

If you overwrite a parent-class' method, you should declare all function parameters in the function definition. If there is a parameter missing, you will get an error.

Example:

```
SomeBehavior extends ModelBehavior
public function afterSave(Model $Model){ } //WRONG, but works in 5.3
public function afterSave(Model $Model, $created){ } //RIGHT, works everwhere :)
```

**Add App::load() to load dependencies**

Always good to check if your class is really available, so double-check if you have all the classes you depend loaded with [App::load()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#App::load) at the beginning of the file.

Comment: you forgot the most important thing: ALWAYS app::uses() all your used classes in this class (at the top of the file). this should fix most of the issues described.

Comment: This was also my first clue, but Class DEBUGGER and STRING should be core classes and loaded by default. Also, I already have all these loaders in place and it worked under 5.4, so I am sure this particular problem has nothing to do with loaded classes.

But since this post became more about good coding practices, I'll add it to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: never assume core classes are loaded by default. they will not be if they are not used so far. ok. good to hear that :)

Comment: oh, and if you are lazy, you will find all of the above changes and many more in my upgrade shell: https://github.com/dereuromark/upgrade - one click and you should have them all converted automatically.

Comment: You are right about the core classes. The issue was that I don't even use DEBUGGER and STRING classes in the mentioned code, making these errors even more senseless.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution is to change the error reporting level in Core.php to:

```
Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
    'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT,
    'trace' => true
));
```

Please note, this is NOT an ideal solution, fix your code!

Comment: Is hiding error messages an alternative to fatal errors?